# How to test observable containing a debounce operator?

Tags: jasmine, rxjs

How does one write a Jasmine test to test an observable with the `debounce` operator? I've followed [this blog post](https://blog.hyphe.me/rxjs-testing-in-real-world-applications/) and understand the principles of how it should be tested, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Below is the factory that I am using to create the observable:

```
import Rx from "rx/dist/rx.all";
import DOMFactory from "../utils/dom-factory";
import usernameService from "./username.service";

function createUsernameComponent(config) {
  const element = DOMFactory(config);

  const username = Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent(element.find('input'), 'input')
    .pluck('target', 'value')
    .startWith(config.value);

  const isAvailable = username
    .debounce(500)
    .tap(() => console.info('I am never called!'))
    .flatMapLatest(usernameService.isAvailable)
    .startWith(false);

  const usernameStream = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(username, isAvailable)
    .map((results) => {
      const [username, isAvailable] = results;
      return isAvailable ? username : ''
    })
    .distinctUntilChanged();

  return Object.freeze({
    stream: usernameStream,
    view: element
  });
}

export default createUsernameComponent;
```

Note that `tap` operator is never called by the test. However, it will be executed properly if I run this code on the browser.

Below is my attempt at the test:

```
import Rx from "rx/dist/rx.all";
import Username from "./username.component";
import DataItemBuilder from "../../../test/js/utils/c+j-builders";
import usernameService from "./username.service"

describe('Username Component', () => {
  let input, username;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const usernameConfig = DataItemBuilder.withName('foo')
      .withPrompt('label').withType('text').build();

    const usernameComponent = Username(usernameConfig);
    usernameComponent.stream.subscribe(value => username = value);

    input = usernameComponent.view.find('input');
  });

  it('should set to a valid username after debounce', () => {
    const scheduler = injectTestSchedulerIntoDebounce();
    scheduler.scheduleRelative(null, 1000, () => {
      doKeyUpTest('abcddd', 'abcdd');
      scheduler.stop();
    });
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.advanceTo(1000);
  });

  function injectTestSchedulerIntoDebounce() {
    const originalOperator = Rx.Observable.prototype.debounce;
    const scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();

    spyOn(Rx.Observable.prototype, 'debounce').and.callFake((dueTime) => {
      console.info('The mocked debounce is never called!');
      if (typeof dueTime === 'number') {
        return originalOperator.call(this, dueTime, scheduler);
      }
      return originalOperator.call(this, dueTime);
    });

    return scheduler;
  }

  function doKeyUpTest(inputValue, expectation) {
    input.val(inputValue);
    input.trigger('input');
    expect(username).toBe(expectation);
  }
});
```

When I run the test, the fake `debounce` never gets called. I plan to mock the `username` service once I can get past the `debounce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test code you are triggering the input event inside the `scheduleRelative` function. This doesn't work because you are advancing 1000ms before doing the change. The debouncer then waits 500ms to debounce the `isAvailable` call but you already stopped the scheduler so time is not advancing afterwards.

What you should do is: trigger the input event before advancing the scheduler time or even better in a `scheduleRelative` function for a time <= 500ms in a and then inside the `scheduleRelative` function for 1000ms you have to call the `expect` function with the expected output and then stop the scheduler.

It should look like this:

```
  it('should set to a valid username after debounce', () => {
    const scheduler = injectTestSchedulerIntoDebounce();

    scheduler.scheduleRelative(null, 500, () => {
      input.val(inputValue);
      input.trigger('input');
    });

    scheduler.scheduleRelative(null, 1000, () => {
      expect(username).toBe(expectation);
      scheduler.stop();
    });

    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.advanceTo(1000);
  });
```

In addition to that I have better experience with `scheduleAbsolute` instead of `scheduleRelative` because it is less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As per Simon Jentsch's answer, below is the answer using `scheduleAbsolute` instead of `scheduleRelative`:

```
import Rx from "rx/dist/rx.all";
import Username from "./username.component";
import DataItemBuilder from "../../../test/js/utils/c+j-builders";
import usernameService from "./username.service"

describe('Username Component', () => {
  let input, username, promiseHelper;

  const scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler(0);

  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(usernameService, 'isAvailable').and.callFake(() => {
      return Rx.Observable.just(true);
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    const usernameConfig = DataItemBuilder.withName('foo')
      .withPrompt('label').withType('text').build();

    const usernameComponent = Username(usernameConfig, scheduler);
    usernameComponent.stream.subscribe(value => username = value);

    input = usernameComponent.view.find('input');
  });

  it('should set the username for valid input after debounce', (done) => {
    doKeyUpTest('abcddd', '');
    scheduler.scheduleAbsolute(null, 100, () => {
      expect(usernameService.isAvailable).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(username).toBe('');
    });
    scheduler.scheduleAbsolute(null, 1000, () => {
      expect(usernameService.isAvailable).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(username).toBe('abcddd');
      scheduler.stop();
      done();
    });
    scheduler.start();
  });

  function doKeyUpTest(inputValue, expectation) {
    input.val(inputValue);
    input.trigger('input');
    expect(username).toBe(expectation);
  }

});
```